# Redirected you too many times in drupal

Tags: drupal-7, redirect, drupal-modules, drupal-views

We are getting "redirected you too many times" error after giving redirection. All inner pages are working properly but the home page is not working without login into the drupal admin side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [middleware.dev redirected you too many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635635/middleware-dev-redirected-you-too-many-times)

Answer (score -1):

It seems once you are visiting home page, there could be any condition for redirect which is looping, that 's why you are getting this error,did you implement any custom  module.also check your .htaccess file.